# How can i add some static text above the editor?

Tags: editor, metabox

I created a custom post type and i want to display some text on the editor page below the title and above the text editor. How can i do this?

I tried using add_meta_box, but i wasn't able to move it above the editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way would be using JavaScript to inject the element.

Here's the gist of the markup for that page:

```
<div id="poststuff">

    <div id="post-body" class="metabox-holder columns-2">
        <div id="post-body-content">
            <div id="titlediv">
                ... other stuff ...
            </div>

            <div id="postdivrich" class="postarea">
                ... other stuff ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `titlediv` is the title.  The `postdivrich` is the content editor.  You want to insert something *between* them.  Using jQuery, this is pretty easy.  Just tell it to insert your markup after the `titlediv`:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var text_to_insert = "This is some text you'll throw between the title and editor.";

    $('<p>' + text_to_insert + '</p>').insertAfter('#titlediv')
});
```

Here is the result of using that exact code on my own site:

[image: Inserting text before the editor.]

Comment: Thanks, its fine for me, but you have to admit, an action to insert some content or something else like that would be better:)

Answer (score 14):

new hooks for the add/edit post screen: 
**edit_form_after_title**

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'myprefix_edit_form_after_title' );

function myprefix_edit_form_after_title() {
echo '<h2>This is edit_form_after_title!</h2>';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

We add a [Custom Meta Box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and do our thing inside it.

There are [some hooks](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.2/src/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php) that are **not** Meta Boxes and we can use to insert content into that admin page:

```
add_action( 'edit_form_top', function( $post ) 
{
    echo '<h1 style="color:red">edit_form_top</h1>';
});

add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', function( $post ) 
{
    echo '<h1 style="color:red">edit_form_after_title</h1>';
});

add_action( 'edit_form_after_editor', function( $post ) 
{
    echo '<h1 style="color:red">edit_form_after_editor</h1>';
});

add_action( 'edit_page_form', function( $post ) 
{
    // edit_page_form is ONLY for pages, the other is for the rest of post types
    echo '<h1 style="color:red">edit_page_form/edit_form_advanced</h1>';
});

add_action( 'dbx_post_sidebar', function( $post ) 
{
    echo '<h1 style="color:red">dbx_post_sidebar</h1>';
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To anyone with this problem, check this post: [More hooks on the edit screen](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/01/more-hooks-on-the-edit-screen/) It allows to insert custom content by new native Wordpress hook, which is by far more stable sollution.

### Mentioned hooks

- edit_form_after_title
- edit_form_after_editor
- edit_form_advanced

Use as described in @DrMosko's answer.